# In Tensorflow, is there a simple way to register a callback function for when model checkpointing happens?

Tags: tensorflow

I was looking at the code from a Tensorflow's implementation of a text encoder model called Skip-thought Vector models: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/skip_thoughts.

The code in the training script contains the following:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver()

tf.contrib.slim.learning.train(
  train_op=train_tensor,
  logdir=FLAGS.train_dir,
  graph=g,
  global_step=model.global_step,
  number_of_steps=training_config.number_of_steps,
  save_summaries_secs=training_config.save_summaries_secs,
  saver=saver,
  save_interval_secs=training_config.save_model_secs)
```

Apparently, a model checkpoint is saved every `training_config.save_model_secs` seconds.

I wonder if there's a way to register some kind of callback function that gets called after model checkpointing happens every time. Specifically, I want to move/copy the model checkpoints to some other network locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CheckpointSaverListener` (see [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py)) would be a way to go but it would require to use a `MonitoredTrainingSession` instead of relying on the slim api and therefore you would need to reimplement some of the logic of `slim.train` method.

```py
# Class example from TensorFlow link above
class ExampleCheckpointSaverListerner(CheckpointSaverListener):
    def after_save(self, session, global_step_value):
        print('Done writing checkpoint.')
    ...

# Pseudo-code to illustrate how to use it
your_hooks = [ExampleCheckpointSaverListerner()]
step = 0
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.train_dir,
                                       chief_only_hooks=your_hooks) as sess:
    # Your training loop
    while step < num_loop:
        _, step = sess.run([train_tensor, model.global_step], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. I guess this is my only option in Tensorflow. I chose to run a completely separate thread in parallel instead of rewriting the Tensorflow code. This also allows some flexibility in what I want to while adding some complexity in handling possible conflicts in multithreading (e.g., an thread tries to copy a model file while the file is being written). But anyways for what I wanted to do, I was able to run a separate thread lock-free.

Comment: Is there a way to [have callbacks outside of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878198/can-i-have-hooks-callbacks-outside-a-session)?