# Can Tensorflow programs use off-the-shelf Keras callbacks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Can Tensorflow programs use off-the-shelf Keras callbacks, when the machine learning program is using native Tensorflow and no other apis from Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, maybe check the [keras implementation inside native Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks). It has all callbacks in Keras. And you should be able to write your own callbacks just like in Keras. There might be 2 caveats:

1. Tensorflow keras and Keras do have small differences.
2. It might be tricky if you want to use these callbacks outside `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create your own callback function in TensorFlow?

EDIT: Oh nevermind, didn't see the part about native TF.

EDIT 2: Is this useful?: [In Tensorflow, is there a simple way to register a callback function for when model checkpointing happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44269387/8841462)